# How to use classes from plugin's "lib" folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I created plugin in Rails 4.2.3 which also has some classes in its "lib" folder:

```
lib/xxx/some_class.rb
```

Next, I created application and included that plugin as gem:

```
gem 'myplugin', path: "/path/to/plugin/myplugin"
```

Unfortunately SomeClass is not visible from within application.

I'm wondering what is best method to include that and other classes from plugin's "lib" folder. I know that in application's application.rb file I could add:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["/path/to/plugin/myplugin/lib/**/"]
```

But I don't like that I have to explicitly specify entire path to the "lib" folder. Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it should be enough:

```
require 'xxx/some_class'
```

In the file using your `SomeClass`. To give you an insight on what bundler will do for you (and Rails), they will `require` for you the file in `lib/yourplugin.rb`, if you `require 'xxx/some_class'` in that file, it will be "autoloaded" in rails, otherwise you just need to require it in the files you need.

Comment: Unless you specify `require: false` in your Gemfile, Bundler will do this for you, won't it?

Comment: Not exactly. Bundler will only require the file located in `lib/yourpluginname.rb`, if your file is named `lib/xxx/some_class.rb` and you don't add `require 'xxx/some_class'` in your `lib/yourpluginname.rb`, it won't be added. Bundler **requires only one file for you**

Answer (score 0):

This should work out-of-the-box. Have a look at [ActiveRecord's `lib/` tree](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib), there's a subdirectory, too.

I guess you're not specifying the module that Rails' auto-loading sets up for subdirectories.

Example: Even though ActiveRecord comes with a class `Base`, that class won't be visible without the namespace. That's why you use `ActiveRecord::Base` in your models.

If your plugin puts the classes under `lib/my_plugin/some_class.rb`, Rails will find the class when you specify `MyPlugin::SomeClass` but not just `SomeClass`.